# Match a data frame columns to another data frame rows content

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame as follows

| A | B | C | D | ... | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

and another data frame in which every column has zero or more letters as follows:

| Letters |
| --- |
| A,C,D |
| A,B,F |
| A,H,G |
| A |
| B,F |
| None |

I want to match the two dataframes to have something like this

| A | B | C | D | ... | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

make example and desired output for answer

Example:

```
data = ['A,C,D', 'A,B,F', 'A,E,G', None]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['letter'])
```

df :

```
    letter
0   A,C,D
1   A,B,F
2   A,E,G
3   None
```

`get_dummies` and `groupby`

```
pd.get_dummies(df['letter'].str.split(',').explode()).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

output:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0
1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0
2   1   0   0   0   1   0   1
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Not working on my dataset not sure what is the reason. Is there a way which involves both dataframes?

Comment: Even because of this, you should make example for answer.